# Linux subsystem на Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, wsl

Windows 7 Enterprise позволяет использовать WSL. Я включил её в настройках

[image: скриншот]

но не понимаю, что делать дальше, чтобы стало можно её использовать.

Во всех инструкциях под десятку говорится, что надо установить какой-нибудь линукс из магазина windows, но ведь в семёрке магазина нет. Что делать?

Comment: Это не WSL, это [старьё ещё из девяностых](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5_UNIX)

Comment: @andreymal, ой.. А зачем оно надо? Кстати, может тогда ответ напишешь?

Comment: Где-то читал, что оно чисто для галочки для соответствия каким-то там требованиям правительства США. Но где я это читал, я забыл, и ответ не напишу, да и в общем-то это всё что я знаю)

Comment: А тебе оно вообще нафига? Там из фишек - nfs-client, который не факт, что работает с pNFS.

Comment: @donRumata, я bash хотел, но его нету, похоже ((

Comment: На 7 тока через `mingw\cygwin`. Ну и в составе `git for windows` вроде как идёт.

Answer (score -1):

нажми `win+r` и введи `bash` у меня заработала

Comment: А какая у вас версия?

Comment: Не может оно просто так взять и заработать.